# potty training at night

Tags: toddler, potty-training

My son is 2, going on three. He's doing really well during the day for potty training. He tells me when he needs to go.

How do I do this with him at night? Diapers are too small. He's in a six for diapers at night, and pulls-ups are more expensive then diapers.

I'm a first time mother and this is all new to me. I need help, please!

Comment: Related: [How do I stop my 3yr old from wetting the bed at night?](http://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/5596/how-do-i-stop-my-3yr-old-from-wetting-the-bed-at-night)

Comment: Also related (particularly the first answer!) [How do you potty train for overnight?](http://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/199/how-do-you-potty-train-for-overnight?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to economize by getting the child up to use the potty once or twice during the night, and then re-use the pull-up the next night if it is dry in the morning.

The related question anongoodnurse found has some great stuff in it.  Definitely review that!

There's an alarm you can buy that makes a terrible racket when the first couple of drops of pee come out.  But your child is much too young now to use this to learn to wake up enough to get up to pee.